# Large user data and request handling in Corda

Tags: block, blockchain, rpc, corda, distributed-apps

I am making a Cordapp to store User data as states in Corda. I am expecting around 1000-2000 rpc users to user this Cordapp. Will Corda be able to handle such a load? What all things should I keep in mind while writing the Cordapp ton handle the load?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how many transactions each user performs per second.

In Corda Enterprise 3.0, nodes can perform over 1,000 TPS under certain conditions, which equates to 86.4 million transactions a day. See the table here: https://docs.corda.r3.com/sizing-and-performance.html#overview.

We expect further performance improvements in Corda Enterprise 4, planned for release at the end of 2018.